# Chaining Lists Together In Python With Condition Matching

Tags: python, list

**Premise:**

I have lists of two-word phrases that I need to try to daisy chain together.

I have twelve lists with thousands of paired entries in each list, and I need to find all possible chains of the entries through the lists.

The order of the lists relative to each other is fixed -- list3 follows list2 follows list1, etc. I have a solution, but it is decidedly old-school and not very Pythonic -- and it takes forever to run. My last run took 3 hours and 40 min, which is completely unworkable.

So, I'm looking for any solutions that would be more efficient and (hopefully) speed up the process to something that is manageable.

**Input Format:**

The input data is formatted as 2D lists, like this:

```
l1 = [ ['SHORT', 'FILM'], ['LEASE', 'BACK'], ['SHELF', 'LIFE'], ['HOLDS', 'FAST'], ... ]
l2 = [ ['BOAT', 'DECK'], ['FAST', 'FOOD'], ['FILM', 'PROP'], ['CHOW', 'LINE'], ... ]
l3 = [ ['FOOD', 'DRIVE'], ['PROP', 'PLANE'], ['GOAL', 'LINES'], ['WRAP', 'PARTY'], ... ]
.
.
.
l12 = [ [ ...
```

**Output:**

I need to find all possible chains of words that match the second word of each pair on a list with the first word on the next list, etc, daisy chaining all the way through.

The code I have (shortened to only three lists for brevity) looks like:

```
l1 = [['SHORT', 'FILM'], ['LEASE', 'BACK'], ['SHELF', 'LIFE'], ['HOLDS', 'FAST']]
l2 = [['BOAT', 'DECK'], ['FAST', 'FOOD'], ['FILM', 'PROP'], ['CHOW', 'LINE']]
l3 = [['FOOD', 'DRIVE'], ['PROP', 'PLANE'], ['GOAL', 'LINES'], ['WRAP', 'PARTY']]

ans = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
        for j in range(len(l2)):
                if  l1[i][1] == l2[j][0]:
                        for k in range(len(l3)):
                                if l2[j][1] == l3[k][0]:
                                        item = [l1[i][0], l1[i][1], l2[j][1], l3[k][1]]
                                        ans.append(item)

print(ans)
```

Which gives the output of::

```
[['SHORT', 'FILM', 'PROP', 'PLANE'], ['HOLDS', 'FAST', 'FOOD', 'DRIVE']]
```

Any suggestions on a more efficient and faster(!) way to do this?

## **ADDITIONAL INFORMATION AND CONSTRAINTS**

I have found out more details on this that provide additional constraints that will change the code.  First off, there are not really 12 lists, there are three lists that repeat (in order) 4 times: list1, list2, list3, list1, list2, list3, etc.

Also, the list needs to "circle" back at the end so that the second word of the pair in list12 (same as list3) matches the first word in the pair of list1 `(l12[j][1] == l1[k][0])`.

For example, in order for the chain:

```
HORSE BACK FLIP PHONE HOME RUNS SHORT FILM PROP PLANE RIDE HIGH
```

to be a valid solution, `HIGH HORSE` must be on list12/list3.

Also, because the three lists repeat four times and circle around, the four loops

```
HORSE BACK FLIP PHONE HOME RUNS SHORT FILM PROP PLANE RIDE HIGH
PHONE HOME RUNS SHORT FILM PROP PLANE RIDE HIGH HORSE BACK FLIP
SHORT FILM PROP PLANE RIDE HIGH HORSE BACK FLIP PHONE HOME RUNS
PLANE RIDE HIGH HORSE BACK FLIP PHONE HOME RUNS SHORT FILM PROP
```

are considered to be the same word loop and the dupes should be removed.

The code snippet I am using is:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
  for j in range(len(list2)):
    if  list1[i][1] == list2[j][0]:
      for k in range(len(list3)):
        if list2[j][1] == list3[k][0]:
          for l in range(len(list1)):
            if list3[k][1] == list1[l][0]:
              for m in range(len(list2)):
                if list1[l][1] == list2[m][0]:
                  for n in range(len(list3)):
                    if list2[m][1] == list3[n][0]:
                      for o in range(len(list1)):
                        if list3[n][1] == list1[o][0]:
                          for p in range(len(list2)):
                            if list1[o][1] == list2[p][0]:
                              for q in range(len(list3)):
                                if list2[p][1] == list3[q][0]:
                                  for r in range(len(list1)):
                                    if list3[q][1] == list1[r][0]:
                                      for s in range(len(list2)):
                                        if list1[r][1] == list2[s][0]:
                                          for t in range(len(list3)):
                                            if list2[s][1] == list3[t][0] and list3[t][1] == list1[i][0]:
                                              item = [list1[i][0], list1[i][1], list2[j][1], list3[k][1], list1[l][1], list2[m][1], list3[n][1], list1[o][1], list2[p][1], list3[q][1], list1[r][1], list2[s][1]]
                                              ans.append(item)
```

Which gives me all the loops, but doesn't remove the duplicates. And... takes hours to complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without even looking deeper I can tell you to start studying the iteration protocol. Python allows you to avoid using indexes

Comment: Does each word only show up once in the first position within a single list?

Comment: @Steve No. There can be any combination of words in the lists. And words can repeat in either the first or second positions. The two words in each pair will never be the same word, however. For example, you wouldn't see ['BLUE', 'BLUE']. And, there are no dupes in the word pairs on each list. But, the same word pairs can show up on separate lists.

Comment: Ok, well then I've shown you the basic idea in my answer, but it's going to have to get more complicated.  The dictionaries built at the beginning will have the same keys, but will now have to have lists of words as values to cover the fact that words in the first position in a list can be repeated.  You'll then have to iterate over those lists so that you can deal with the multiples entries.  I think recursion is going to be your friend here, to avoid a whole bunch of messy complexity of doing otherwise.  Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: If you can't do this yourself, I might take a shot at it if you can give me a dataset that has some repeated first words in it, and you can give me the expected result as well.  The more test data you can give me, the better, as long as you can give me an expected result you're confident in to go with it.  I do TDD quite religiously, so that correct expected result is solid gold to me.

Comment: What would be cool is if you could go ahead and fill out my example with your full dataset and run it.  It won't find all the chains, but unless you have lots of duplicate in the first position words, it should still give you a good idea of how fast the approach is. - I'm really curious to hear what that number is.

Comment: @Steve I can definitely send you the data I am working with and the output from my code. I am new to this site, so how do I forward the text files to you? Also, I just noticed you are in Mill Valley, CA --- which is where I live too. Wow. Of all places. Small world.

Comment: Hey.  Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  I want to put together a recursive version that can handle the duplicate first position words.  I can modify the data I have for that case, and then send it to you to try with more data.

Comment: I just read your update.  I'm not sure I understand the wrap-around part.  Are you saying that there may be a particular sequence that uses all 12 lists but starts with the second or third list, so it has to wrap around?  Another way of putting that, I think, is to say that there are 14 lists instead of 12, and you want all of the sequences that use 12 of the lines, no matter which line they start on.  Is that a correct statement?  That's the way I'd code it, I think, since it would be easier than wrapping around.

Comment: Are you a new programmer or just new to SO? Is there any chance you could code this (and might want to) with some direction from me?  This really shouldn't be a very hard problem.  The biggest thing should be understanding how to build the maps for each of the three lists, which is now just a bit more complicated than what's in my posted code.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for getting back to me and for your attention. It's awesome. So, I started programming in 1975, so not new to coding. But, I haven't done much coding at all in the last decade or so. I just started with Python six months ago and I only need it for very specific tasks, so I am just barely scratching the surface. If you are willing to work with me on this, I would be grateful. I've had some thoughts on optimizing this. I am new to this site and don't know the protocol. Do we do it all here? Or, start communicating directly?

Comment: @Steve On your wrap-around question, what I mean is that the first and last words of the 12-word chain need to connect (think of a circle). The second condition in `if list2[s][1] == list3[t][0] and list3[t][1] == list1[i][0]:` in my code above is what I am talking about.

Comment: Oh..ok, got it.  That's actually easier to do than what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build dictionaries from each of your lists so that you can do fast lookups for each connection, not having to iterate over the entire next list looking for a match.  This should save you tons of time.  I haven't done much with Big O notation, but I think this turns a O(N^2) problem into a O(N) problem.

Here's how to do this for the cut down example you give.  It should work just as well (much better, actually) for your 12 long lists:

```
l1 = [['SHORT', 'FILM'], ['LEASE', 'BACK'], ['SHELF', 'LIFE'], ['HOLDS', 'FAST']]
l2 = [['BOAT', 'DECK'], ['FAST', 'FOOD'], ['FILM', 'PROP'], ['CHOW', 'LINE']]
l3 = [['FOOD', 'DRIVE'], ['PROP', 'PLANE'], ['GOAL', 'LINES'], ['WRAP', 'PARTY']]

# Define a list of our lists so we can iterate over them
lists = [l1, l2, l3]

# For each list except the first one, create an equivalent dictionary where the first value
# in each list entry is a key, and the second value is the corresponding value for that key.
dicts = [{e[0]:e[1] for e in l} for l in lists[1:]]

# Attempt to find a full chain for one of the pairs in list #1
def do_one_chain(pair):
    chain = []
    chain.extend(pair)
    for d in dicts:
        if pair[1] not in d:
            return None
        pair = (pair[1], d[pair[1]])
        chain.append(pair[1])
    return chain

# Iterate over our first list...
ans = []
for pair in l1:
    # Apply our search function to a pair from list #1
    r = do_one_chain(pair)
    # If a chain was found, add it to the answer list
    if r:
        ans.append(r)

# Print the found chains
print(ans)
```

Result:

```
[['SHORT', 'FILM', 'PROP', 'PLANE'], ['HOLDS', 'FAST', 'FOOD', 'DRIVE']]
```

What's nice about this is that the solution is not only much more efficient, it's much cleaner and compact as well.  None of the code changes as you add more levels.  You just have to add the new levels to the `lists` list.  I know this is what you were looking for, dreading having to stretch those nested `if` statements out to 12 levels worth, right?

Please report back how long this algorithm takes to run on your full dataset.

Comment: Maybe instead of returning None return chain so that you find chains of all possible lengths which I suspect is what the OP wants.

Comment: Sure.  That's not a problem.  My expectation would be the opposite, but it doesn't matter.  Either way is just as easy, as you already see. - I just tried it with the sample data.  Unfortunately, there are no examples that go two levels but not three.  I guess I could change that :)

Comment: @lightalchemist  I just tried modifying the data so that there is a two-level chain.  That works just fine.  But I also realize that the OP tells us the result he wants, which is what I'm doing by not returning the short chains.  He gives us the expected output, and it does not include anything but full chains.  It's still possible he only wants to exclude single-length chains, but include anything longer.  However, just returning `chain` instead of `None` will not match his specified output, as all of the single-length chains show up in the list.

Comment: @Steve. This was helpful. I am only interested in full-length (12-word) chains. Not partial length chains. Also, I found out more constraints that may change this significantly. I will edit my question with the additonal constraints.

Comment: @Steve I ran my version of the 12-level nested loops code last night with the three lists I have. The lengths of the list are: list1 (6,614); list2 (8,513); and list3 (231). My code took 3 hours and 30 min and found 5,916 possible loops including the duplicates (I haven't figured out how to remove the dupes yet), yielding 1,479 unique loops.